# Add values to class members of another class type

Tags: vb.net

The following program validates vendor files.

Here are the rules:

- Process 1 vendor at the time
- Validate the following 3 scenarios (vendor sent a file, did not send a file, sent too many files)
- Store the validation outcome in class InvoiceFileValidationClass
- 1 class member of InvoiceFileValidationClass called "Files" is a list of type "ArhiveFilesClass"
- Member "Files" needs to store several file names for archiving purposes
- Adding values to all other member of the InvoiceFileValidationClass is not a problem
- Adding values to member "Files" generates a null exception in the following line of code:
  **ValidateFileCount.Files.Add(temp)**

**Any ideas on how to avoid null exception?**

```
    Public Class InvoiceFileValidationClass
        Public VendorName As String
        Public FileName As String
        Public FileCount As InvoiceFileCount
        Public FileContent As InvoiceFileContent
        Public ErrorMessage As String
        Public Files As List(Of ArhiveFilesClass)
    End Class
    Public Class ArhiveFilesClass
        Public OriginalFilePathandName As String
        Public ArchiveFilePathandName As String
    End Class
Public Enum InvoiceFileCount
    FileMissing
    PassedValidation
    TooManyFiles
End Enum

Public Shared Function ValidateFileContent(Vendor As VendorClass) As InvoiceFileValidationClass
        ValidateFileContent = New InvoiceFileValidationClass
        ValidateFileContent.FileContent = InvoiceFileContent.PassedValidation
        Dim MyUnzippedFolder As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Vendor.FTPInPath)
        Dim LineNumber As Integer = 0
        Dim ErrorLine As String = Nothing
        For Each VendorFile In MyUnzippedFolder.GetFiles()
            If InStr(VendorFile.Name.ToString, Vendor.InvoiceFileMask) <> 0 Then 'match mask
                If File.Exists(VendorFile.FullName) Then
                    REM
                    REM Check File Name Extension
                    REM
                    If VendorFile.Extension.ToUpper <> ".CSV" Then
                        ValidateFileContent.ErrorMessage = Vendor.VendorName & ": did not provide a csv file."
                        ValidateFileContent.FileContent = InvoiceFileContent.NotCSVFile
                    End If

                    REM
                    REM Check Column Count Per Row 
                    REM
                    Using reader As New StreamReader(VendorFile.FullName)
                        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                        While line IsNot Nothing
                            Dim temp As New InvoiceTextFileClass
                            Dim fields() As String = line.Split(",".ToCharArray())
                            If LineNumber > 0 Then 'Do Not Analyze, this is the column header
                                If fields.Length <> Vendor.ExpectedColumnCount Then
                                    ValidateFileContent.FileContent = InvoiceFileContent.IntegrityCheckFailed
                                    ErrorLine = ErrorLine & LineNumber.ToString & ", "
                                End If
                            End If
                            line = reader.ReadLine()
                            LineNumber += 1
                        End While
                    End Using
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If ErrorLine <> Nothing Then
            ValidateFileContent.ErrorMessage = Vendor.VendorName & ": integrity check failed in the following rows (" & ErrorLine & ")."
        End If

        REM
        REM Check File Row Count
        REM
        If LineNumber < 2 Then
            ValidateFileContent.ErrorMessage = Vendor.VendorName & ": empty file."
            ValidateFileContent.FileContent = InvoiceFileContent.FileIsEmpty
        End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example to reiterate our comments

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim test As New TestingSomethingHere    
        test.Files.Add("test") '' THIS WORKS!!!! BECAUSE FILES HAS BEEN INITIALIZED!!!

        Dim test2 As New TestingSomethingElseHere    
        test2.Files.Add("test2") '' THIS DOESN'T WORK!! BECAUSE FILES HASN'T BEEN INITIALIZED!!!

    End Sub

    Public Class TestingSomethingHere    
        Public Files As New List(Of String)    
    End Class

    Public Class TestingSomethingElseHere    
        Public Files As List(Of String)    
    End Class

End Module
```

Notice in my `TestingSomethingHere` class, I use the `New` keyword when I declare `Files`. This tells it that whenever that class is constructed, it automatically initializes that member. (You don't have this)

In my `TestingSomethingElseHere` class, I don't use it (just like you) and when I try to add something to the collection, I get a `NullReferenceException`. This is because `Files` **hasn't been initialized**.

There are many ways to go about initializing it, but the point is **you must initialize it**

---

**To spell it out exactly for you**, this is your class:

```
Public Class InvoiceFileValidationClass
    Public VendorName As String
    Public FileName As String
    Public FileCount As InvoiceFileCount
    Public FileContent As InvoiceFileContent
    Public ErrorMessage As String
    Public Files As List(Of ArhiveFilesClass)
End Class
```

This is what you need.

```
Public Class InvoiceFileValidationClass
    Public VendorName As String
    Public FileName As String
    Public FileCount As InvoiceFileCount
    Public FileContent As InvoiceFileContent
    Public ErrorMessage As String
    Public Files As New List(Of ArhiveFilesClass)
End Class
```

The change being

```
Public Files As List(Of ArhiveFilesClass)
```

Changing to

```
Public Files As New List(Of ArhiveFilesClass)
```

This is one way you initialize objects that require it in .NET